# Sum of vectors to follow a path

Tags: matrix, vector

I'm working with a mathematica program where I have a matrix with the xyz coordinates of the begin and the end of a group of vectors (randomly), here is the image: [image]

How can I sum two vectors where one have the end coordinates equal to the begin of the second and so on? It is possible to assign a label or something?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to translate a given vector so that its beginning is at the end of another vector, but it has same magnitude and direction ?

Comment: I also find it hard to understand your question. Maybe you are looking for `Accumulate`?

Comment: Sorry It's hard to explain. In the picture we see a serie of small vector following a path, I want to sum that vectors to obtain resulting vectors.

Comment: Please provide a bearable subset of your data to play with, together with expected result. If they are always vertical you can start with `GroupBy[ #[[{1,2}]]& ]` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a concrete example dataset:

```
h = 1.5;
epsilon = h/ 2 /10;
pts = Tuples[{
    Subdivide[0., 2., 10],
    Subdivide[0., 1., 5],
    Subdivide[0., h, 10]
    }];
rand = RandomSample[pts, Floor[Length[pts]/2]];
arrows = Transpose[{rand, rand + ConstantArray[h/10 {0, 0, 1}, Length[rand]]}];

Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.0125], Arrow[arrows]}]
```

[image]

Next, we generate a directed graph in which each vertex corresponds to an arrow and in which the directed edge `DirectedEdge[i,j]` means that arrow `i`'s tip equals arrows `j`'s tail. We use `Nearest` to find out all these directed edges in $O(n \, \log(n))$ time instead of $O(n^2)$. The weakly connected components of this graph correspond to the new, longer arrows. `TopologicalSort` ensures that these components are ordered from tail to tip.

```
tips = arrows[[All, 2]];
tails = arrows[[All, 1]];
tipstotails = Nearest[tips -> Automatic, tails, {1, epsilon}];
pos = Flatten[Position[Length /@ tipstotails, 1, 1]];
G = Graph[Range[Length[arrows]], DirectedEdge @@@ Transpose[{Flatten[tipstotails[[pos]]], pos}]];
components = TopologicalSort[Subgraph[G, #]] & /@ WeaklyConnectedComponents[G];
newarrows = Table[Join[{tails[[comp[[1]]]]}, tips[[comp]]], {comp, components}];

Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.01], Arrow[newarrows]}]
```

[image]

Although I haven't tested it, this should also work if the arrows do not all point into the same direction, e.g. if they follow a curved path -- as long as tips and tails match up to `epsilon`.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, this give me a clearer idea of how to solve my problem!! :D

Comment: You're welcome. If you like, you can mark this answer as "accepted" by clicking on the gray checkmark to its left.